# Missing some absolute methods on ByteBuffer

Tags: java

Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way but I'm missing some *absolute* put methods on [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

If you look at `ByteBuffer` you'll see that most of the put methods have both an absolute and a relative variant.

Except for:

- Writing parts of a `byte` array into the `ByteBuffer`.
- Writing a `ByteBuffer` into the `ByteBuffer`.

..and I need exactly those.

To be clear `ByteBuffer` has methods:

```
 put(byte[] src, int offset, int length)
 put(ByteBuffer src)
```

but is lacking:

```
 put(int index, byte[] src, int offset, int length)
 put(int index, ByteBuffer src)
```

I have reasons why I do not want to move the buffer's position pointer, hence I only want to use absolute put methods.

Any idea why those methods have been left out?

I can of course mimic the missing methods without moving the buffer's position pointer but that will involve looping over the source bytes. The Javadoc clearly states that theses methods are (potentially) much more efficient than moving than looping and moving the bytes one-by-one. I believe the Javadoc because my tests indicate the same. I need to squeeze out as much speed I can from my implementation so therefore I'm of course inclined to take advantage of whatever bulk methods I can get my hands on .... if only they existed.

Incedentially [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) is also missing an absolute `get` method for partial byte array move. But I don't actually need such a method currently. But again strange it doesn't exist.

Comment: Just a follow-up. Have found this http://thesoftwarelife.blogspot.dk/2009/10/java-bytebuffer-annoyances.html which seems to be complaining about roughly the same thing.

Comment: I'd argue that the absolute methods are more useful and important than the relative ones. If I were redesigning that API, I'd leave out all of position, flip, rewind, mark, reset, and so on and focus on providing just the memory access, leaving it as basically a heavyweight array with C `union`-like features.

Comment: @Boann - so would I. Exactly the way I think of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to get the methods you need is to have a second ByteBuffer sharing the same memory, so you can change its position without changing the position of the original.

Unfortunately, the [`slice`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice%28%29) method does not take a position parameter either; instead it uses the current position of the original buffer. So you cannot do:

```
dstBuffer.slice(100).put(srcBuffer);
```

Here are some ideas, in no particular order except it's the order I thought of them:

- If it fits with the way you're using the buffer, you can prepare a copy of the buffer with `slice()` and keep that around for when you need to put data at a position independent of the original's position.
- If the position you want to absolute put at is always greater or equal to the original buffer's position pointer, you can do:

  ```
  dstBuffer.slice().position(desiredPosition - dstBuffer.position()).put(srcBuffer);
  ```

<strike>That won't work to put at an earlier position, unfortunately, since the position on the slice is not allowed to be negative.</strike> **EDIT**: Never mind, I forgot about the [duplicate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#duplicate%28%29) method. See @BorisBrodski's great answer.

- If you are not using direct byte buffers, System.arraycopy is easy and fast:

  ```
  System.arraycopy(
      srcBuffer.array(), srcBuffer.arrayOffset() + srcBuffer.position(),
      dstBuffer.array(), dstBuffer.arrayOffset() + desiredPosition,
      srcBuffer.remaining()
  );
  ```
- If concurrent access is not necessary, then you can temporarily change the buffer's position when you need to do an absolute put and put it back afterwards. If you need concurrent access but the thread contention is low, you can synchronize all access to the buffer (maybe obvious, but included for completeness):

  ```
  synchronize (lock) {
      int originalPosition = dstBuffer.position();
      dstBuffer.position(desiredPosition);
      dstBuffer.put(srcBuffer);
      dstBuffer.position(originalPosition);
  }
  ```
- If none of the other ideas work for you, you can hack the buffer. This is messy, but here's an example:

  ```
  private static final sun.misc.Unsafe UNSAFE;
  static {
      Object result = null;
      try {
          Class<?> klass = Class.forName("sun.misc.Unsafe");
          for (Field field : klass.getDeclaredFields()) {
              if (field.getType() == klass &&
                  (field.getModifiers() & (Modifier.FINAL | Modifier.STATIC)) ==
                      (Modifier.FINAL | Modifier.STATIC)) {
                  field.setAccessible(true);
                  result = field.get(null);
                  break;
              }
          }
      } catch (Throwable t) {}
      UNSAFE = result == null ? null : (sun.misc.Unsafe)result;
  }

  private static final Field ADDRESS_FIELD;
  static {
      Field f;
      try {
          f = Buffer.class.getDeclaredField("address");
          f.setAccessible(true);
      } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {
          f = null;
      }
      ADDRESS_FIELD = f;
  }


  public static void absolutePut(ByteBuffer dstBuffer, int dstPosition, ByteBuffer srcBuffer) {
      if (!srcBuffer.isDirect()) {
          absolutePut(dstBuffer, dstPosition,
              srcBuffer.array(), srcBuffer.arrayOffset() + srcBuffer.position(),
              srcBuffer.remaining());
          return;
      }

      if (UNSAFE != null && ADDRESS_FIELD != null && dstBuffer.isDirect()) {
          try {
              long dstAddress = (long)ADDRESS_FIELD.get(dstBuffer) + dstPosition;
              long srcAddress = (long)ADDRESS_FIELD.get(srcBuffer) + srcBuffer.position();
              UNSAFE.copyMemory(srcAddress, dstAddress, srcBuffer.remaining());
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
      } else {
          // fallback to basic loop
          for (int i = srcBuffer.position(); i < srcBuffer.limit(); i++) {
              dstBuffer.put(dstPosition + i, srcBuffer.get(i));
          }
      }
  }

  public static void absolutePut(ByteBuffer dstBuffer, int dstPosition, byte[] src, int srcOffset, int length) {
      if (UNSAFE != null && ADDRESS_FIELD != null && dstBuffer.isDirect()) {
          try {
              long dstAddress = (long)ADDRESS_FIELD.get(dstBuffer) + dstPosition;
              UNSAFE.copyMemory(
                  src, UNSAFE.arrayBaseOffset(byte[].class) + srcOffset,
                  null, dstAddress,
                  length);
          } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
      } else {
          // fallback to System.arraycopy
          System.arraycopy(
              src, srcOffset,
              dstBuffer.array(), dstBuffer.arrayOffset() + dstPosition,
              length);
      }
  }
  ```

I've given this code some minimal testing with mixes of direct and non-direct buffers and it ***seems*** okay. If the reflection techniques fail (e.g., because you are within an applet security sandbox or the Java implementation is not compatible) it can fall back to plainer methods.

Comment: It's interesting that you are very concerned with concurrency. Though ByteBuffer is not intended to be used concurrently, and there's no guarantee that any of its methods, even absolute get, are thread safe, we can still reasonably assume some concurrency and use the buffer concurrently, in some particular applications. (most apps use ByteBuffer non concurrently)

Comment: @Boann. Thank you for that. I was kind of pursuing the slice route myself but I end up with a zillion ByteBuffers which all have to live somewhere. What still puzzles me is why these methods are lacking. Perhaps there's something I've missed. And yes, I'm unfortunately in a situation where I'm using direct buffers, otherwise I concur that the `System.arraycopy()` solution would be good.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, those methods where left out, since no other such methods exists. There are bunch of absolute methods taking primitives including "byte", but no absolute methods taking *array* of primitives.

The solution could be:

```
((ByteBuffer)buffer.duplicate().position(index)).put(src, offset, length);
((ByteBuffer)buffer.duplicate().position(index)).put(otherByteBuffer);
```

Comment: Although it has a little object creation overhead, this is the best solution I reckon. It's short and sweet and does the job.

Comment: Agree. It looks sweet. I'll have to test if the performance impact of the object creation is negligible or not. If using this solution I would execute the above for each and every write operation I want to do. Seems like a lot of overhead but sometimes we (or more correctly myself) see performance problems where there are none. :-). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

```
static void put(ByteBuffer buffer, int index, ByteBuffer src)
{
    int p0 = buffer.position();
    buffer.position(index);
    buffer.put(src);
    buffer.position(p0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not a solution. You are shifting the destination's position pointer (because you do `buffer.position(index)`) which means your solution does not have the characteristics of an absolute put method. (which is that it leaves the position pointer unchanged)

Comment: @nolan6000: You're putting the destination's position pointer exactly back where it started, which is indeed a perfectly valid solution to this problem.  +1 for this legit solution.

Comment: @nolan6000 uh? the position is changed back to it's origin value.

Comment: Nope, you are CHANGING the position pointer. Perhaps only a microsecond, but you are CHANGING it !!   (doesn't matter that you put it back to the original value)

Comment: @nolan6000 ByteBuffer is not expected to be thread safe. If your requirements include thread safety, your question should have pointed that out. Now if thread safety is required, we need to ask whether `duplicate()` is thread safe if the solution uses it. It certainly should be, but there's no guaranteed in javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using for an absolute bulk `get()`:

```
// Perform a bulk get() that doesn't modify the buffer
public void get(ByteBuffer buf, int position, byte[] dest, int off, int len) {
    if (buf.hasArray())
        System.arraycopy(buf.array(), buf.arrayOffset() + position, dest, off, len);
    else if (len < 256) {        // 256 is a wild guess TODO: performance testing
        while (len-- > 0)
            dest[off++] = buf.get(position++);
    } else
        ((ByteBuffer)buf.duplicate().position(position)).get(dest, off, len);
}
```

A similar approache works for `put()`.